# How to print very large string using Logcat

Tags: android, android-logcat

I'm printing a large string using this method :

```
   private static final int LOGCAT_MAX_LENGTH = 3950;

    private void logLongJsonStringIfDebuggable(String s) {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            while (s.length() > LOGCAT_MAX_LENGTH) {
                int substringIndex = s.lastIndexOf(",", LOGCAT_MAX_LENGTH);
                if (substringIndex == -1)
                    substringIndex = LOGCAT_MAX_LENGTH;
                Log.d("TAG", s.substring(0, substringIndex));
                s = s.substring(substringIndex).trim();
            }
            Log.d("TAG", s);
        }
    }
```

This works fine, but Logcat prints too many strings that I can not see all of the content of the string in my Logcat. I can see only most recent ones.
Can you tell me how I can view all Logcat logs in Logcat? Or can you show me a way to print all logs to a file or something like that? Thanks.

Comment: use `java.util.logging.Logger` with one of available `java.util.logging.Handler`s, for example:  `java.util.logging.FileHandler`

Comment: @pskink Thank you, but can you show an example please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write your log on file, so your log-reset problem will not be there and you can see full log.

Use below command on terminal

```
adb logcat > path_of_file/LogFile.log // Extension can be .txt also
```

Comment: You mean cmd on windows?

Comment: Correct. And if you did not added adb on path we set for Java, then write relative path of adb at place of adb.

Comment: I get `'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`. How can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: Tell me the path of adb at your machine. It will be into 'android-sdk-windows\platform-tools'

Comment: I can't find it.. I'm using Android Studio

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103004/discussion-between-pankaj-kumar-and-jason).